# Console.WriteLine Doesn't Support Turkish Characters In Dotnet Web Api Application

Tags: c#, .net-core, encoding, utf-8, console.writeline

In console app:

```
Console.WriteLine("şşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşş");
```

Output shows me in a correct way but when I write the same code line in dotnet web api

Output:

```
ÄŸÄŸÄŸÄŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸ
```

What I've tried so far:

```
Console.OutputEncoding= Encoding.UTF8;
```

thanks for your efforts in advance.

P.S. sorry for grammar rules

Comment: This is working for me. What font are you using for your console? Mine's set to "Lucida Console"

Comment: It's a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `"şşş".encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1254')` returns `'ÅŸÅŸÅŸ'` (the same for `"şşş".encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')`).

Comment: What font are you using for your console?
I never change anything on console. it is set default settings. @MatthewWatson

Answer (score 3):

Add `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);`.

Normally this compiles as expected in .NET 6: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dkpMlY

However, you might be in an environment that extra encodings are not loaded. You can check the list with `Encoding.GetEncodings();`.

Comment: Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            Console.WriteLine("şşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşş");

I wrote above code but it gives me the same result (ÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸÅŸ) :/ thanks anyway.

Comment: you mentioned that it works in .net 6. Yes I know and it also works in dotnet core 3.1 console app. But in dotnet core web api app doesn't work as expected

Comment: Are you adding `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` to your Startup.cs or Program.cs in your web app?

Comment: I even added it just one line behind the Console.WriteLine. Now I also added into startup.cs, it doesn't work